# ADT 20 Setting layout height/width in property list

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using eclipse's graphical interface editor whenever possible-- the XML editor seems to be quite buggy; some text doesn't appear (or appears in the wrong place and/or distorted) until I scroll through the file with the up/down arrow keys.

Anyway, I recently "upgraded" to r20 of the android development tools.  In previous versions, I could manually set things like layout height and width right from the property list (if I wanted to set a height to 20dp, I could edit it from the property list for example).  Now, it only gives the "fill parent" and "match content" options, and you cannot type anything in.

So, is there any way to do this now?  Is this behavior normal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've noticed the same and restarting Eclipse made no difference for me. It's a known bug apparently. [Cannot free-form enter values for weight, height](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33978&q=match_parent&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

All things considered R20 has been a very poor quality upgrade with far too many bugs that could have been spotted with a bit of regression testing.

Comment: Restarting Eclipse doesn't fix the issue for me.  Is the next step to do a complete reinstall, you think?  What a bother...

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this issue by restarting eclipse.

I hope that will work with you.